# How do I format a number in thousands in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a number like 123542.52.  How do I display that number to the nearest thousand? In this example, 124 should be displayed.

Comment: `round(123542.52/1000)`? Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: You seem to be asking for number of thousands, which would be your number divided by 1000 rounded to the nearest integer.  Do you actually want 124000?

Comment: I'm looking for a clean way to format very large numbers.  I have a plot with many labels like 123542.52, but those labels take up a LOT of space.  They really only need to be shown to the thousand place and I can't figure out a clean way to format the numbers.

Comment: that sounds like you should change an option in the function you are plotting with (especially if you are using ggplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's `sprintf("%.0f", 123542.52/1000)` ?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a negative digits argument in round():

```
round(123542.52, -3)/1000
# [1] 124
```

As described in `? round`:

> Rounding to a negative number of digits means rounding to a power of ten, so for example `round(x, digits = -2)` rounds to the nearest hundred.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
 x = 123542.52
 y = signif(x,3)
 y <- as.numeric(gsub("0","",y))
```

Comment: Is that what you are looking to achieve?